# Multiple different Stack Exchange profiles with one myOpenID account?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts, openid, myopenid

I'm trying to have different "identities" on some of the different Stack Exchange sites (e.g., one for my professional activities, and a different one for my hobbies) such that they have different profile information (name, email, avatar, etc.) and other Stack Exchange users don't necessarily realize they're owned by the same real person. However, I'd also like to use the same OpenID provider account to log in to all of them. I'm using myOpenID in case it matters, which allows me to create different profiles (name, email, etc.) and specify which to use when I log in to a site.

However, I noticed that when I log in to a Stack Exchange site and create an account, even if I choose one of the different profiles on myOpenID, the profile on my Stack Exchange account has all the same info as my master Stack Exchange account. If I delete the info from my profile and save, next time I log in it gets all the info back again. In other words, I can't seem to *prevent* my Stack Exchange profiles from syncing! Is there any way around this, or am I going to have to create two different accounts with OpenID providers in order to ensure completely separate accounts with Stack Exchange?

(Just to be clear, I don't mind if it's the same account behind the scenes, s.t. Stack Exchange itself knows the different profiles belong to the same person. I just don't want it to be obvious to the casual fellow user.)

Comment: *Why* don't you want multiple accounts to be seen as the same person?  What purpose would this really serve?  What valid use case is there for a feature like this?

Comment: So...use a pseudonym while you're online, then?  Don't post any embarrassing information under your real name?  (I believe there's even a way to contact moderators to have them disassociate information from your account, if you *really* want to take it that far).  In essence, I'm not sure why this sort of feature could be seen as useful on Stack Exchange's end - why not use different email addresses instead, if you wanted to resort to this?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do - different email address, and all the other profile information. However, StackExchange seems to sync it or otherwise not let it be different, when I log in with the same OpenID provider account. I'd like to avoid having to log out and log back in when I switch between StackExchange sub-sites. (Mind you, I don't want different identities on the same sub-site, just on different ones.)

Comment: Perhaps a better example of one where I'd like anonymity would be politics.stackexchange.com (I don't know if this actually exists - haven't looked.) Now matter what I say there will rub _someone_ the wrong way. If I want to avoid that baggage being publicly tagged to my real identity, I need to use an alternate identity. Either that or just not participate. I'd prefer not to be forced to do the latter when there are interesting StackExchange sites to join...  Also, there may be some sites where simply being a member is what I don't want shared, never mind what I say there.

Comment: So this is the last justification I'll give. I know some people out there think nobody needs to worry about anonymity if they simply don't say/do anything wrong. However, I disagree, because "wrong" is in the eye of the beholder, and not everyone is as open minded as you. If you still fall into that camp, however, that's fine; just please don't try to convince me that my question is invalid. The purpose of StackExchange is to answer questions, not debate their validity or premise. Thank everyone! (PS - Sorry for being verbose, but thanks for reading this far!!)

Comment: Use differend openIDs and different browsers!

Comment: @ŁukaszLech from my original question, "However, I'd also like to use the same OpenID provider account to log in to all of them." By that I mean not only the same OpenID provider, but the same OpenID account as well. Also, although I didn't explicitly state so in the original question, I do not want to have to use different browsers to do this either.

Comment: @DaveLillethun OK there may be some misunderstanding here. By the same OpenID provider you understand, for example, Google, where you use 2 separate gmail accounts?

Comment: @ŁukaszLech So "Google" would be a provider, and "me@gmail.com" and "myself@gmail.com" would be examples of two different accounts with the same provider. "Facebook" on the other hand would be a different provider. So long story short... What I see is that StackExchange has spearate profiles for my account on each sub-site, but when I log in with the same OpenID account it seems impossible to (intentionally) get the profiles out of sync... (In which case, what's the point of separate profiles?)

Comment: @DaveLillethun OK I've understood it differently. It should work... are you sure you're logged out of google before relogging to SE? Maybe your account got associated when you logged in from other google account when you were still logged on SE?

Comment: @ŁukaszLech I'm not sure I see what Google has to do with it...? They're not the OpenID provider that I use to log in to SE.

Comment: I'm surprised that a solution hasn't been offered after six years.  I completely understand the reason:  It isn't to be anonymous, but spare other users from Too Much Information (TMI), especially if one has many areas of expertise and wide interests.  For example, my being an electrical engineer is of little value to members of the Seasoned Advice (cooking) forum. To make a profile universally useful, it would have to be trimmed down to the point of being useless, saying, e.g., nothing more than "Person".